# Remove shortcuts from home screen

Tags: android, shortcut, android-package-managers

I am trying to remove **all shortcuts from all screens** in android. I succeed it once but somehow it stopped working after next execute. Could I ask you to help me find out what would be the problem? There is not stack, there is no error, just I click and nothing happens. When I first managed to success I got many toasts describing that "X was removed".

Here is my code:

```
private void method0() {
    final Intent anyIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    List<ResolveInfo> pkgAppsList = this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(anyIntent, 0);
    for (final ResolveInfo resolveInfo : pkgAppsList) {
                method(resolveInfo);
    }
}

private void method(ResolveInfo resolveInfo) {
    try {
        final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        String packageName = ((ActivityInfo) resolveInfo.activityInfo).packageName;
        String appName = (String) resolveInfo.loadLabel(pm);
        ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName, resolveInfo.activityInfo.name);

        if (packageName.startsWith("com.google") || (packageName.startsWith("com.android")))
            return;

        final Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        shortcutIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, componentName.getClassName()));

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, appName);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(packageName, componentName.getClassName()));
        intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");

        sendBroadcast(intent, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I added also permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

I am using standard launcher for Nexus 4 - original image ROM from google site.

Comment: See this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853443/android-how-to-remove-uninstall-application-shortcuts-from-home-screen

Comment: There is no requirement for any home screen implementation to support the code that you have listed.

Comment: @CommonsWare means _launcher apps are not required to add functionality to handle UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT intent and remove shortcuts from home screen_

Comment: I wanted to use on original rom for android withoud any additional launchers

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not using default Stock android launcher.

Please check this [example](http://androidsurya.blogspot.in/2014/01/Android-Add-and-Remove-Application-Shortcut-in-Home-Screen-Example.html).Hope that helps.

Comment: as I said it worked once and the somehow it stopped working. I am talking about all shortcuts on screens not only this shortcut for current app.

Comment: Are you able to remove shortcut of current App every time?

Comment: Also check this [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480287/trying-to-uninstall-shortcut-but-shortcut-wont-go-away)?