# How to change the icons at bottom of home screen programmatically

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, homescreen

I created a contacts app, and I wish to replace the default contacts app. The problem is that their icon is in the bottom location of the home-screen.

Even if the user would like to use my app, they will constantly get a reminder of the old system contacts app, in the most central place of the device. How can you compete that?

So is there anything I can do?

- Can I replace the default contacts app icon in the bottom of the home screen?
- Is there a way to track when default contacts is launched and launch my app instead?
- Is there anything else that can be done here?

Note, I am aware of the ability to place your app shortcut in the home screen. And also I am aware of the intent to show a specific contact,call a number and send SMS, in this question I only want to talk about the scenario that app is launched from icon.

Comment: Replacing an app, or  forcibly having users go to yours seems like a security issue

Comment: @cricket_007 This is what most of my users asking me for. This is the common non developer person expectation: "Just give me a button that does that..."

Comment: And there's many contact book applications in the app store, but none can "overwrite" or prevent a user from opening the stock application, as far as I know. At least not without root

Comment: Have a look @ [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853443/android-how-to-remove-uninstall-application-shortcuts-from-home-screen).  It would require you to know the Intent details of the competing app.

Comment: @pathfinderelite it looks like half the answer I need! Now need to figure out how to install my shortcut in the bottom of the home-screen