# how to remove shortcut of app in android

Tags: android

I have created two buttons one for **create shortcut** and another for **remove shortcut**. **create shortcut** code works well,but **remove shortcut** doesn't work above **api level 21**

here is the code

```
 private void deleteShortCut() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "RAM CLEANER");
        intent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.short_cut_icon));
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction("com.yzy.shortcut");
        i.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, i);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
        SharedPreferencesUtils.setIsShortCut(getApplicationContext(), true);

        Intent shortcutInt = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                Setting.class);
        Intent addInt = new Intent();
        addInt.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutInt);
        addInt.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Ram Booster");
        // Set Uninstall action in Intent
        addInt.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        // Broadcast the created intent
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addInt);
    }
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853443/android-how-to-remove-uninstall-application-shortcuts-from-home-screen

Comment: thanks for reply.i have already used that code. but this code doesn't work for above api level 21 (Lollipop, Marshmallow, N).